# How to pass JavaScript errors to Google Analytics using Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager

I've read this article:
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/7679411?hl=en

It's pretty straight forwards:

> To configure a JavaScript error trigger:
>
> ```
> Click Triggers and then New.
> Click Trigger Configuration and choose the JavaScript Error trigger type.
> ```

But my question is, now that I have set up a trigger, do I need to do something else to ensure it is passed to Google Analytics?

And where will it appear so I can test it is working?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the article is not quite complete. Any trigger has to be matched with a tag, in this case a Universal Analytics Event tracking tag (I do not believe there is another appropriate way to send it). Ours had the following values:

Category: `JavaScript Error`

Action: `{{Error Message}}`

Label: `{{Error Line}}: {{Error URL}}`

I say "had" because we have discontinued this tracking. It generated a lot of useless hits (things like Action: `Script error.`, Label: `0:`), and a whole lot of hits total, many of which were errors we couldn't do anything about because they were from 3rd-party scripts.

You may find it more useful, but I recommend that, if possible, you send these events to a different GA property. If you don't have one, consider filtering them out of your main view and using them in your unfiltered view or a dedicated error view.

Comment: Great advice, thank you.  I would hope not to have any errors, but on the odd occasion I did have it would be useful to know about them.

Comment: As a side question, can I simply do `console.error("My test error");` in the console and generate an error to test?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think `console.error` is caught as a JS error - you can try it, but if I remember correctly ours never showed up in GA. They were just differently-colored `console.log` messages.

Comment: No, you're right.  It's using `window.onload` and since my window is not loading, that would mean it doesn't show up.  Thanks for your help.  I'll generate an error in the code and then it should show.